# Removing Duplicate from Arraylist and Getting the duplicate of one property in a list

Tags: java, arraylist

i have one arraylist say "templist" it will have  items of item say "Stool"

now list contains duplicates

> 1 abc wwww.com lob1
>   1 abc wwww.com lob2

now i want like

> 1 abc wwww.com  (lob1,lob2)

may be a separated list of lob's alone. how we can do it ? please help

```
List tempList = new ArrayList();
```

I added items of type `ServiceItem` ( which has property like `id`,`name`,`url`,`lob`)).
Like said i will duplicates for `id`,`name`,`url` as these three can be mapped to different `lobs`.

I want first three property to be one entry and last property should be list of differnt `lobs`.

I made Changes to the code. now. Here is the code. Tell me how to achieve the result as 1 | ABC , BCA

public class ListTest {

```
public static void main(String args[]){

    List TestList = new ArrayList();

    MyBean myBean = new MyBean();
    MyBean myBean2 = new MyBean();
    myBean.setId("1");
    myBean.setLob("ABC");
    myBean2.setId("1");
    myBean2.setLob("BCA");

    TestList.add(myBean);
    TestList.add(myBean2);

}
```

}

public class MyBean {

```
    private String id;
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getLob() {
        return lob;
    }
    public void setLob(String lob) {
        this.lob = lob;
    }
    private String lob;
```

}

Comment: A bit unclear. More explanation will help us getting the best answer

Comment: added more code and updated the question

Answer (score 2):

Create a set from your list will remove the duplicate, ex:

```
Set set = new HashSet(templist)
```

Comment: Ok here is the explanation. My arraylist is having data like the below                                                              APS | http://a.net/aps/| ABC
APS|http://a.net/aps/|BCA                  i want a final list having one entry for the first three values and abc,bca for last (may be another list inside the list)

Comment: @Rajesh, I still can't understand it properly. Can you edit the question and format the explanation. A bit code will be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I would do the following:

1. Use Map instead of using List.
2. Remove lob from ServiceItem.
3. Override `equals` and `hashCode` methods of ServiceItem (to make sure dups won't be inserted).
4. Insert new entry into map where key is this ServiceItem and value is a list (or better set if lobs are unique). Check if `contains`(ServiceItem) - then add new lob to the list (set) of the value.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i solved the problem using apache collections multihashmap . but as of 3.2 it is deprecated so i used 3.1 version.

here is the final code.

```
public class ListTest {

public static void main(String args[]){

    List<MyBean> TestList = new ArrayList<MyBean>();

    MyBean myBean = new MyBean();
    MyBean myBean2 = new MyBean();
    myBean.setId("1");
    myBean.setLob("ABC");
    myBean2.setId("1");
    myBean2.setLob("BCA");

    TestList.add(myBean);
    TestList.add(myBean2);

    for(int i=0;i<TestList.size();i++){
        MyBean result = (MyBean)TestList.get(i);
        System.out.println("ID:"+result.getId());
        System.out.println("Lob:"+result.getLob());
    }

     MultiMap mhm = new MultiHashMap();
     for(int i=0;i<TestList.size();i++){
         MyBean result = (MyBean)TestList.get(i);
         mhm.put(result.getId(), result.getLob());
     }

     List list = (List) mhm.get("1");

     for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++){
         System.out.println(list.get(i));
     }

}
```

}``

Comment: MultiMap from Google Guava seems better. http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html